# Difference between HttpRequestMessage.Headers and HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Could anyone please explain the difference between  `HttpRequestMessage.Headers` and `HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers`.

The documentation for `HttpRequestMessage.Headers` says Gets the collection of HTTP request headers.

And for `HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers` - The content headers as defined in RFC 2616.

This doesn't help me a lot. What would be practical differences and which should be used?

Answer (score 2):

We can see some properties defined in [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), searching for **Header Field Definitions** in the file, then we can see them should have a mapping with the properties of `HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers`, they are introduced in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders?view=net-5.0#properties).

It is literal meaning. And in my opinion, I think the differences are, e.g. when using jquery ajax in javascript, we adding all the request headers in the `headers` object, like

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer token"
        },
        success: function(data) {alert(data);}
    })
```

But when we using HttpClientFactory in asp.net core, we have to set different http headers to different properties, so these are what I think as the differences. And these are the properties defined in [HttpRequestMessage.Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders?view=net-5.0). You can see that they provides different properties.

[image]